# Java [HOW TO] passing object as parameter

Tags: java, function, object

I have this function which I want to call with this: `MouseHover("btnAttackHover.png",btnAttack);`

```
Image btnAttack;
 public void MouseHover(String i,Image e){
            ImageIcon btn = new ImageIcon("src/images/btn/"+i);
            e = btn.getImage();
    }
```

When I call it,this should change the image and draw this:

g.drawImage(btnAttack,100,100,100,100,null);

But the `e = btn.getImage();` doesn't work.

How can I pass the Image Object "btnAttack"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    public Image MouseHover(String i){
        ImageIcon btn = new ImageIcon("src/images/btn/"+i);
       Image  e = btn.getImage();
     return e;
     }
```

Now if you want to draw image just do this:

```
  g.drawImage(g.MouseHover(..),100,100,100,100,null);
```